# Split file (base64Data with btoa)

Tags: javascript, upload, base64, google-drive-api

I tried to upload a file to Google Drive by its protocol "resumable" in Javascript. The fact is that tells me to send pieces of the file.

For this I have gone through btoa base64Data.

But ... Now how should I break it into pieces 1000000 KB?

The help really appreciate it. I'm really stuck.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
reader.onload = function(e)
   {
   var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
   var metadata = {
   'title': fileData.name,
   'mimeType': contentType
   };
   var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
   //Now what should I do?
   }
```

Comment: fileData.slice(...)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: thanks ... but I see that it is very complex. We surprised I did not find any example of drive searching google google "file.webkitSlice and drive". 

This disappointed me a lot the sdk Google Drive. :(